# How do I suppress specific loggers in java.util.logging?

Tags: java, logging, javafx, java.util.logging

I'm trying to get processable logs of deep issues occurring with a JavaFX WebView.

This configuration (unsurprisingly) gives me masses of events unrelated to my problem:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level= FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
```

I specifically get many events like this obscuring the real issue I am trying to find:

```xml
<record>
  <date>2019-02-23T15:05:45</date>
  <millis>1550946945429</millis>
  <sequence>12936</sequence>
  <logger>com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPathImpl</logger>
  <level>FINE</level>
  <class>com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPathImpl</class>
  <method>addLineTo</method>
  <thread>18</thread>
  <message>WCPathImpl(1,361).addLineTo(600,516)</message>
</record>
```

I tried to suppress logging **com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPathImpl** by adding this to logging.properties:

```
com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPathImpl = OFF
```

That didn't work. That logger still logs a firehose of messages I don't need to solve this problem.

I'm trying this to debug [okta-aws-cli](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-aws-cli-assume-role).

How do I suppress specific loggers in java.util.logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logger name isn't sufficient. You need to specify which property you are changing on the logger, in this case **level**.

Instead of this broken configuration:

```
com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPathImpl = OFF
```

Use this configuration specifically referencing the level property of the logger:

```
com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPathImpl.level = OFF
```